# ionic-native/geolocation only works sporadically [No Provider]

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm building a new Ionic project via `ionic new` as following:

`ionic -v`: 3.12.0

`@ionic-native`: 4.3.0

`cordova -v`: 7.0.1

Then I added the cordova plugin and the npm modules:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
```

In the `app.module.ts` I imported it and added it to the providers array:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

providers: [
  StatusBar,
  SplashScreen,
  Geolocation,
  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
```

When I start the app via `ionic serve` it works the first two or three times. But then it suddenly stops working with a error, even though I did not change anything with the imports:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Geolocation!
Error: No provider for Geolocation!
```

When I change the import in `app.module.ts` to `import { Geolocation as NativeGeoLocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation'` it works for 2 or 3 times again and then stops working.

Does anybody know a solution or at least the reason why this is happening?

Comment: The error seems random. You may access the geolocation plugin to early. Do you wait for the `platform.ready()` event before using the plugin?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yeah, I'm accessing it in the `platform.ready().then()` promise. This randomness drives me crazy :-D